# Is there a theorem linking the order of a differential equation and the number of linearly independant solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a theorem linking the order of a differential equation and the number of linearly independant solutions?

So for example when we have a $2^{nd}$ order ODE a general solution would be something like $y(x)=Au(x)+Bv(x)$ for some constants $A,B$ now if we had a third order for example would we expect a gneral solution to look like this?

$y(x)=Au(x)+Bv(x)+Cw(x)$ and so on for higher orders.

Also would this be the same for a ODE like this one $y^{'''}+y=0$ where we don't have all derivative of $y$ apprearing neccessarily?

Thanks.

Comment: So you do not want any boundary constraints?

Comment: You can take a look at this......http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624717/number-of-arbitrary-constants-in-the-general-solution-of-an-ode

Comment: @Aniket: I don't think that answer in the link is a rigorous answer! :)

Comment: But set of solutions of general differential equation doesn't form linear space... For me it's kinda strange to ask about linear-independence property when set of solutions is not linear space.

Answer (score 1):

A homogeneous linear equation with continuous coefficients
$$
y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}(x)\,y^{(n-1)}+\dots+a_1(x)\,y'+a_0(x)\,y=0
$$
has $n$ linearly independent solutions.

Comment: Emphasize: this is for *linear* ODE.  The question does not say linear.  But it should.